# Why do we include compare function inside definition of struct while sorting vector of custom objects?

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, struct

Why do we do this:

```
struct MyStruct
{
    int key;
    std::string stringValue;

    MyStruct(int k, const std::string& s) : key(k), stringValue(s) {}
};

struct less_than_key
{
    inline bool operator() (const MyStruct& struct1, const MyStruct& struct2)
    {
        return (struct1.key < struct2.key);
    }
};

std::vector < MyStruct > vec;

vec.push_back(MyStruct(4, "test"));
vec.push_back(MyStruct(3, "a"));
vec.push_back(MyStruct(2, "is"));
vec.push_back(MyStruct(1, "this"));

std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), less_than_key());
```

Here in the above code snippet why is the `operator()` function included in `struct less_than_key`. What happens if I take it out of the struct definition?

Comment: You mean, using regular function instead of functor ?

Comment: "What would happen if I take it out of the struct definition? " Have you tried it out?

Answer (score 4):

> What would happen if I take it out of the struct definition?

Assuming you do it intelligently, nothing terrible. Your sample could just as easily be rewritten as:

```
bool less_than_key(const MyStruct& s1, const MyStruct& s2)
{
    return (s1.key < s2.key);
}

std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), less_than_key);
```

But now the comparison is done via an indirect call. The algorithm will have to call the function via a function pointer. That can be harder to inline.

On the other hand, the call via the functor **object** is resolved statically. The compiler has more type information. It knows the type that function is a member of. It resolves the call directly. And that can be more easily inlined.

The difference is in how much the compiler can glean from the type information it is given.

Also, it should be noted that you can have all of the above without the hassle of choosing a name for a new type. C++11 introduced lambda expressions, and their closure types. You can easily rewrite your code to this idiomatic form:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](const MyStruct& s1, const MyStruct& s2){
  return (s1.key < s2.key);
});
```

There's just as much type information present as there was in the named struct version. You are just saved the hassle of dealing with boiler-plate, and get to have the comparison criteria embedded in the call to sort itself.

Comment: *In some circumstances* a compiler can still inline the free function version, particularly when this is the only comparator you sort `MyStruct`s with, in this translation unit. The function object version is **easier** to inline.

Answer (score 0):

According to [`std::sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) documentation, its `Compare` type argument must be a

> comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of Compare) which returns ​true if the first argument is less than (i.e. is ordered before) the second.

In other words, this version of `std::sort`'s third argument must be a function or a function object, something which can be invoked with the `operator()`. Without that operator in `less_than_key`,

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), less_than_key());
```

is ill-formed (won't compile).

---

With C++11 and following, you could write:

```
std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
    [] (const MyStruct& lhs, const MyStruct& rhs) {
        return (lhs.key < rhs.key);
});
```